# R: Adding data.frame (including numbers and characters) to cells in another data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

What I want to do is like this:

```
> a <- data.frame (col1=c(NA,NA,NA,NA), col2=c(NA,NA,NA,NA), col3=c(NA,NA,NA,NA))
> b <- data.frame(cola="test", colb=1)
>  a[1,2:3] <- b  
> a
  col1 col2 col3
1   NA  test    1
2   NA   NA   NA
3   NA   NA   NA
4   NA   NA   NA
```

However, what I got by executing the code above is :

```
> a
  col1 col2 col3
1   NA    1    1
2   NA   NA   NA
3   NA   NA   NA
4   NA   NA   NA
```

**How can I add characters to specific rows in another data.frame?**

I could add characters to a single cell, but it seems characters are automatically converted to numbers if I add two or more.

```
> a[1,2] <- "test"
> a
  col1 col2 col3
1   NA test   NA
2   NA <NA>   NA
3   NA <NA>   NA
4   NA <NA>   NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `b$cola` is a factor. It will work, if you transform the column values to character strings.

```
b$cola <- as.character(b$cola)
a[1,2:3] <- b
a
#   col1 col2 col3
# 1   NA test    1
# 2   NA <NA>   NA
# 3   NA <NA>   NA
# 4   NA <NA>   NA
```

Comment: It certainly does work, but can you explain what is going on here? `<-` checks for the type of the first element of the replacement `b$cola`, finds that it is a type (factor) that cannot be assigned to `a[1, 2]`, moves to the second element of the replacement `b$colb`, assigns it, and then recycles it?

Comment: @fgnu It has nothing to do with recycling. Internally, factor values are represented as integers (starting with 1). In the original command, the internal value is assigned to `a`, not the label of the factor level.